# Are RandomAccessFile writes asynchronous?

Tags: java, file-io

Looking at the constructor of [RandomAccessFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#RandomAccessFile%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29) for the mode it says 'rws' `The file is opened for reading and writing. Every change of the file's content or metadata must be written synchronously to the target device.`

Does this imply that the mode 'rw' is asynchronous? Do I need to include the 's' if I need to know when the file write is complete?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are RandomAccessFile writes asynchronous?

The synchronous / asynchronous distinction refers to the guarantee that the data / metadata has been safely to disk before the `write` call returns.  Without the guarantee of synchronous mode, it is possible that the data that you wrote may still only be in memory at the point that the `write` system call completes.  (The data will be written to disk eventually ... typically within a few seconds ... unless the operating system crashes or the machine dies due to a power failure or some such.)

Synchronous mode output is (obviously) slower that asynchronous mode output.

> Does this imply that the mode 'rw' is asynchronous?

Yes, it is, in the sense above.

> Do I need to include the 's' if I need to know when the file write is complete?

Yes, if by "complete" you mean "written to disc".

Answer (score 3):

That is true for `RandomAccessFile` and java.io classes when using multiple threads. The mode "rw" offers asynchronous read/write but you can use a `synchronous` mode for read and write operations.